# Basic features that Mongoose added to MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

What are the basic features that Mongoose added to MongoDB? I am wondering to explicitly know their feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is an Open Source, NoSQL database management system that contains

- Indexing
- Load Balancing
- Replicated file storage over
- Ad hoc queries
- List item

  multiple servers, Data aggregation, Server-side Javascript execution and Capped collections.

MongoDB is a *document-based* database management system which leverages a JSON-style storage format known as binary JSON, or BSON, to achieve high throughput. JSON makes it easy for applications to extract and manipulate data, as well as allowing properties to be efficiently indexed, mapped, and nested in support of complex query operations and expressions.

Where as MongooseJS is an Object Document Mapper (ODM) that makes using MongoDB easier by translating documents in a MongoDB database to objects in the program. Besides MongooseJS there are several other ODM’s that have been developed for MongoDB including

- Doctrine
- MongoLink
- And Mandango

There are some advantages of using Mongoose versus native MongoDB like:
`MongooseJS provides an abstraction layer on top of MongoDB that eliminates the need to use named collections`.
`Models in Mongoose perform the bulk of the work of establishing up default values for document properties and validating data`.
`Functions may be attached to Models in MongooseJS. This allows for seamless incorporation of new functionality`.
`Queries use function chaining rather than embedded mnemonics which result in code that is more flexible and readable, therefore more maintainable as well`.

Mongoose did not come with only advantages but there are disadvantages like abstraction that comes at the cost of performance compared to that of native MongoDB.

But the net result of Mongoose is the simplification of database access from applications.